# Get REAL_AGE based on my birthday in JavaScript

Tags: javascript

I wrote a function that works, but I think it can be written much better.

```
  export const getRealAge = () => {
      const today = new Date()
      const DATE_OF_BIRTH = new Date(1997, 9, 16)
      const ONE_DAY = 1000 * 60 * 60 * 24
      const REAL_AGE = Math.round(
        Math.abs((today - DATE_OF_BIRTH) / (ONE_DAY * 365))
      )

      return REAL_AGE
    }
```

Comment: You'd be better off posting this to [Code Review Stackexchange](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/)

Comment: Can you elaborate more on what you mean by "better" ?

Answer (score 0):

I changed the variable names a little because I didn't see the need to use caps here. I tried to make the code as readable as possible too.

Your solution has the problem that it might not be too precise, it's hard to take into account leap-years that way.

```
export const getRealAge = (year, month, date) => {
  const today = new Date();
  const birthday = new Date(year, month, date);
  let age = today.getFullYear() - birthday.getFullYear();
  const monthsDiff = today.getMonth() - birthday.getMonth();
  const turnsThisMonth = monthsDiff === 0;
  const turnsAtLaterMonth = monthsDiff < 0;
  if(turnsAtLaterMonth) {
      age--;
  } else if (turnsThisMonth){
      if (today.getDate() < birthday.getDate()) {
          age--;
      }
  }
  return age;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Your solution is not bad.
It proposes a small modification,
with the use of the library the moment and method diff (which takes into account the leaps years) that @edu mentioned.

```
const today = moment()
const birth = moment([1997, 9, 16])

const getRealAge = (birth,today) => today.diff(birth,'year')

// test
console.log( getRealAge(birth,today))
```

Comment: dzięki Grzesiek, ale importowanie całej biblioteki moment (nie wiem ile tam może być linii) tylko dla jednorazowego użytku jest bez sensu:)

Comment: I think it's better if you write in English. The library is not heavy, it has other interesting features. You can finally use the tree shaking to remove the unused code.

Comment: And it's tested.